# How to test null hypothesis of "observer A sights animal at the same time that observer B sights animal"

Tags: hypothesis-testing, modeling, biostatistics

I have 2 observers at different platforms making sightings of animals in the wild. Observers work independently of one another. Observers record when an animal was sighted, as well as the location of sighting.

For the animals sighted by both observers (I did the matching based on the species, location, and time of sighting) I would like to know how the time of sighting compares for the observers.  My null hypothesis would be something like: animals are observed at the same time by both observers.  The alternate hypothesis would be something like: observer A observes animals before observer B.

I'm not sure how to test this. It seems as though the observations are paired, but I don't know how to properly capture the timing aspect.

I've looked at ranking the times (not quite right) and have looked at time of onset, but that's not quite right either. I think I just may not know the proper terminology for this type of test.

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: It isn't clear what the difficulty is.  You appear to want to compare sighting times, where for each animal there are two times: one for each observer.  This looks like a standard paired testing situation.  What exactly is the difficulty about the "timing aspect"?